# Merging Dataset without loosing values

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two datasets together based on dates

My objective is to get the data for each date (including those where some data will be missing), so under the format
01/01/2021
02/01/2021
...

However, using the Merge function leads to most of the data becoming NA

```
jointdataset <- merge(group_df, group_tweet, by = 'date', all.x= TRUE)

structure(list(date = c("01/01/2021", "01/05/2021", "01/06/2021", 
"01/07/2021", "01/11/2021", "01/12/2021"), `length(category)` = c(4L, 
8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L), `sum(usd_pledged)` = c(50278.64, 366279.590415302, 
172073.0471292, 230.537553792, 304353.5676352, 285277.861423738
), `sum(backers_count)` = c(2880L, 6588L, 3528L, 16L, 4204L, 
6632L), `length(text)` = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), `sum(public_metrics.x$reply_count)` = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), `sum(public_metrics.x$like_count)` = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), `sum(public_metrics.x$retweet_count)` = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here are samples of both of my datasets

```
dput(head(group_df))
structure(list(date = c("01/01/2021", "01/05/2021", "01/06/2021", 
"01/07/2021", "01/11/2021", "01/12/2021"), `length(category)` = c(4L, 
8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L), `sum(usd_pledged)` = c(50278.64, 366279.590415302, 
172073.0471292, 230.537553792, 304353.5676352, 285277.861423738
), `sum(backers_count)` = c(2880L, 6588L, 3528L, 16L, 4204L, 
6632L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

dput(head(group_tweet))
structure(list(date = structure(c(18628, 18629, 18630, 18631, 
18632, 18633), class = "Date"), `length(text)` = c(1324L, 1548L, 
1297L, 1585L, 1636L, 1583L), `sum(public_metrics.x$reply_count)` = c(882L, 
1252L, 910L, 1018L, 810L, 1000L), `sum(public_metrics.x$like_count)` = c(22859L, 
24375L, 17854L, 20341L, 19521L, 19401L), `sum(public_metrics.x$retweet_count)` = c(8621L, 
8239L, 6141L, 6728L, 6938L, 6842L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Is there any way for this data to not become NA ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `full_join` from `dplyr`. Your dates columns should have the same type (Thanks to @TarJae!). You can use the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
group_df %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>%
  full_join(group_tweet) %>% 
  arrange(date)
#> Joining, by = "date"
#> # A tibble: 9 × 8
#>   date       `length(category)` `sum(usd_pledg…` `sum(backers_c…` `length(text)`
#>   <date>                  <int>            <dbl>            <int>          <int>
#> 1 2021-01-01                  4           50279.             2880           1324
#> 2 2021-01-02                 NA              NA                NA           1548
#> 3 2021-01-03                 NA              NA                NA           1297
#> 4 2021-01-04                 NA              NA                NA           1585
#> 5 2021-01-05                  8          366280.             6588           1636
#> 6 2021-01-06                  4          172073.             3528           1583
#> 7 2021-01-07                  4             231.               16             NA
#> 8 2021-01-11                  4          304354.             4204             NA
#> 9 2021-01-12                 12          285278.             6632             NA
#> # … with 3 more variables: `sum(public_metrics.x$reply_count)` <int>,
#> #   `sum(public_metrics.x$like_count)` <int>,
#> #   `sum(public_metrics.x$retweet_count)` <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think format is `mdy` in `group_df` or vice versa in `group_tweet`?! :-)

Comment: @TarJae, I think you are right! Thank you for being sharp this early!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your kind message 
However, when doing so i get the following error 
```
Error in `full_join()`:
! Can't join on `x$date` x `y$date` because of incompatible types.
i `x$date` is of type <date>>.
i `y$date` is of type <character>>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```
Does the mean i have to change the date type beforhand ?

Comment: Hi @Daworn, Did you run my complete code? It says that your dates are not the same. When you include this part `mutate(date = mdy(date))` it should be fixed. So yes the date type is beforehand changed, before joining.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer
So yes, even by using the same code, word for word, i get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help!

Here is how i managed to fix it: using the code given to me by @Quinten and @TarJae, I mutated the date by itself:

```
group_df = group_df %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy(date))
```

Then, I changed the date in `group_df` to type `character`:

```
group_df$date <- as.character(group_df$date)
```

Following this, a `left_join()` was enough:

```
jointdataset <- dplyr::left_join(group_df, group_tweet)

> dput(head(jointdataset))
structure(list(date = c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", 
"2021-01-07", "2021-01-11", "2021-01-12"), Kickstarter = c(4L, 
8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L), Money = c(50278.64, 366279.590415302, 172073.0471292, 
230.537553792, 304353.5676352, 285277.861423738), Backers = c(2880L, 
6588L, 3528L, 16L, 4204L, 6632L), Twitter = c(1324L, 1636L, 1583L, 
1492L, 1718L, 1781L), replies = c(882L, 810L, 1000L, 1050L, 1376L, 
1387L), likes = c(22859L, 19521L, 19401L, 19875L, 24307L, 28284L
), retweets = c(8621L, 6938L, 6842L, 6875L, 7807L, 10235L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The only issue I have now is that the new dataset will not show me data for dates where there is data for only one of the datasets—but that should be an easy fix.